# RabbitMQ Visualizer Plugin for RabbitMQ 3.9.13

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I am looking for a visualizer as the rabbitmq ui is pretty antiquated. I checked AliceMq and some other spots but looks like nothing is maintained anymore and the readme instructions are not really complete. Does anyone have any other options for a UI plugin I can install on our Linux servers for visualization? RabbitMQ 3.9.13 is the version.

Was expecting for AliceMq to work but it does not have deployment instructions and their site is not correct.

Comment: What is the problem whit the RabbitMQ Management UI?

Answer (score 1):

RabbitMQ 3.9.x is completely out of support. Please upgrade.

Having said that, using Prometheus and Grafana is the recommended way to monitor and visualize your RabbitMQ installation. Please see the [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/prometheus.html).